# Numpy Vectorized Function Over Successive 2d Slices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I have a 3D numpy array. I would like to form a new 3d array by executing a function on successive 2d slices along an axis, and stacking the resulting slices together. Clearly there are many ways to do this; I'd like to do it in the most concise way possible. I'd think this would be possible with `numpy.vectorize`, but this seems to produce a function that iterates over every value in my array, rather than 2D slices taken by moving along the first axis.

Basically, I want code that looks something like this:

```
new3dmat = np.vectorize(func2dmat)(my3dmat)
```

And accomplishes the same thing as this:

```
new3dmat = np.empty_like(my3dmat)
for i in range(my3dmat.shape[0]):
  new3dmat[i] = func2dmat(my3dmat[i])
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Can you not rewrite your `func2dmat` to operate on the full 3D array? YMMV, but tHat is typically the best way to go about this type of vectorizations..

Comment: I could do that, but the loop solution is preferable. I want to be able to concisely operate on a compound data structure (3d matrix) with a function that operates on its constituents (2d matrices)-- and this function should not need knowledge of the larger structure from which those constituents come. That way I only need one function, not special functions for every possible structure containing 2d matrices.

Comment: You want a GUFUNC, like e.g. [`np.linalg.det`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.det.html)... The convention is to make your function act on every 2D array on the last 2 dimensions of the input. If you can write fast vectorized code for that, getting it to work over other axes is just a matter of wisely using [`np.rollaxis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rollaxis.html) and the like. A Python loop solution is hardly ever preferable if you want to take full advantage of numpy.

Comment: Preferable is subjective.. if the slice is big enough the performance difference should be minimal, and the logic of Sean is sound; it isn't the conceptual business of the inner function how many, if any, other axes are present. writing your code to handle that general case when there isn't a tangible performance benefit reeks of premature optimization.

Comment: @Jaime I like the idea of having a function that operates on the last two axes by convention. Thanks for both of your help, going with Eelco's solution for now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am afraid something like below is the best compromise between conciseness and performance. apply_along_axis does not take multiple axes, unfortunately.

```
new3dmat = np.array([func2dmat(slice) for slice in my3dmat])
```

It isn't ideal in terms of extra allocations and so on, but unless .shape[0] is big relative to .size, the extra overhead should be minimal.

Comment: Hmm this looks OK. I'm wondering, is there a way to make `slice in my3dmat` iterate along a different axis than the first?

Comment: you can use np.rollaxis to bring the desired axis to iterate over to the front