# numpy replacing for loop on 2D slices in nD array by vectorizing

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I'm toying with time series data and from a raw X x N ndarray(2 X features, 100 N frames as a dummy starting point) I used np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided to create (N-2) consecutive windows of shape (2,3)
i.e.

```
newShape = [98,2,3]
newStride = [8,800,8]
windowView = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(x = data,shape = newShape, strides = newStride)
```

what I'm searching for is a way to apply a function on all the windows, such as computing a histogram/2d on feature/s inside each window.
I know that neither np.apply_over_axes nor np.apply_along_axis wouldn't do the trick as the functor is not commutative on axes (e.g. sum).

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24392631/numpy-vectorized-function-over-successive-2d-slices?rq=1) ([Numpy Vectorized Function Over Successive 2d Slices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24392631/numpy-vectorized-function-over-successive-2d-slices?rq=1)) post where the answer uses list comprehension.
But as I'd really hate for loops with numpy and that question was from 6 years ago, is there any new(or old) features in numpy that would do the trick?

Comment: So your function can only work with one (2,3) window at a time?  The real value of as_strided, is that it lets you write a function that works all 98 at once.  `np.mean` for example can do that.  Otherwise a plain loop over the windows is as good as anything.

Comment: @hpaulj so how do  write a function that treat each window like a elementary element?

Comment: The iteration I had in mind is: `[fun(window) for window in windowView]`, where `fun` is your function that expects a (2,3) array.  Don't make things more complicated than they have to be.

Comment: but list comprehension is slow isnt it? how can we speed it up? I'm aware of it, but i want better solution

Comment: The thing that's slow is calling your window function 98 times.

Comment: @hpaulj and how will u implement such a function that wouldnt be called 98 times?